# Unity Snake Game, how to make the body follow the head?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I've been making a small game to do with Snake, and I'm struggling as to how I can make the Snake's Body appear and follow the position of the head whenever the snake's head touches the apple. I've managed to get the Snake's body to spawn but I can't get it to follow the head correctly. Can anyone help me and tell me how I can do this? Thanks!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Snake_Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    // variables
    public Vector2 pos;
    private Vector2 moveDirection;
    private float moveTimer;
    private float timerSeconds;

    //Function which runs once when the program starts
    void Start()
    {
        timerSeconds = 0.0167f;
        moveTimer = timerSeconds;
        moveDirection = new Vector2(0.1f, 0);
    }

    //Function which updates itself based on your refresh rate
    public void Update()
    {
        AutoMove();
        ChangeDirection();
        transform.position = new Vector2(pos.x, pos.y);
        transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, AngleCalculator(moveDirection) - 90);
    }

    //Moves the snake 60 units each second
    private void AutoMove()
    {
        moveTimer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (moveTimer > timerSeconds)
        {
            pos += moveDirection;
            moveTimer -= timerSeconds;
        }
    }

    //Changes direction of the snake based on arrow key pressed
    private void ChangeDirection()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            if (moveDirection.y != -0.1f)
            {
                moveDirection.x = 0;
                moveDirection.y = 0.1f;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            if (moveDirection.y != 0.1f)
            {
                moveDirection.x = 0;
                moveDirection.y = -0.1f;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            if (moveDirection.x != -0.1f)
            {
                moveDirection.y = 0;
                moveDirection.x = 0.1f;
            }
        }
        else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            if (moveDirection.x != 0.1f)
            {
                moveDirection.y = 0;
                moveDirection.x = -0.1f;
            }
        }
    }

    //Calculates the angle at which the snake is moving; used to calculate rotation of sprite
    private float AngleCalculator(Vector2 direction)
    {
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        return angle;
    }

    private void SnakeBodySprite()
    {
        GameObject snakeApple = GameObject.Find("SnakeApple");
        Apple_RandomSpawn appleScript = snakeApple.GetComponent<Apple_RandomSpawn>();

        //something here?????
    }
}
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Apple_RandomSpawn : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector2 foodPos;

    void Start()
    {
        SpawnApple();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(foodPos.x, foodPos.y);
        SnakeAte();
    }

    public void SpawnApple()
    {
        foodPos = new Vector2(Random.Range(-17, 17), Random.Range(-9, 9));
    }

    public void SnakeAte()
    {
        GameObject snakeBody = GameObject.Find("SnakeBody");
        GameObject snakeHead = GameObject.Find("SnakeHead");
        Snake_Move snakeMove = snakeHead.GetComponent<Snake_Move>();

        if (foodPos.x <= snakeMove.pos.x + 1 &&
            foodPos.x >= snakeMove.pos.x - 1 &&
            foodPos.y <= snakeMove.pos.y + 1 &&
            foodPos.y >= snakeMove.pos.y -1)
        {
            SpawnApple();
            Instantiate(snakeBody);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I can't help you with your question but if you get too stuck FIMPOSSIBLE GAMES has 2 packages that you can purchase and learn from.  Spine Animator - https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/spine-animator-128322  and Tail Animator https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/animation/tail-animator-121819  I used one of his FREE packages to add movement to my characters hair.  Very easy to use.  Again, cost a few $

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a broad question, so it's hard to answer completely. The thought that comes to my mind is using a Queue of move Vectors for the head, and then applying those movements to the body. You would need a reference to the snake body object, and need to know how many movements the head is from the body. It looks like that might be 60 in your case.

I would add the Queue in this section:

```
Queue<Vector2> moveDirections = new Queue<Vector2>();
SnakeBody snakeBody; // Reference to 1st snake body element
float offset = 60; // ?

private void AutoMove()
{
    moveTimer += Time.deltaTime;
    // enqueue the most recent moveDirection
    moveDirections.Enqueue(moveDirection);

    if (moveTimer > timerSeconds)
    {
        pos += moveDirection;
        moveTimer -= timerSeconds;

        // Get oldest moveDirection from the head to apply to the body
        Vector2 bodyMovement = moveDirections.Dequeue();
        snakeBody.transform.Translate(bodyMovement);
    }

    // If the queue count is greater than how far ahead the head should be from the
    // first body element, remove one from queue.
    if (moveDirections.Count > offset) {
        moveDirections.Dequeue();
    }
}
```

This would only work for the first body element, so you could add a script to each body element keeping track of its child body element. Position the child element with the same logic used above.

NOTE: I haven't tested this, I'm just trying to give a high-level overview of how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

We use `LinkedList<Transform> snake` to store snakes, and because a linked list is easy to modify references between nodes, it's almost naturally suited to representing a snake.

When the head moves, just let the position of the tail transform to the previous position of the head, while modifying the references to the nodes of the linked list.

[image: snake movement]